# Star System planetary body orbital software

Tags: windows, simulation, scientific-computing, calculator

I am looking for software to input planetary bodies and use it to determine distances between each body at certain times. 
Software doesn't need to be 3D but needs to be graphic.

I know there are software packages like Universe Sandbox but I would greatly prefer something that is free and relatively easy to learn as I am a student. I have most of the required information for planetary bodies, orbital distance, eccentricity, mass and so on.

Running on Windows 10. As for price, at most I'd say less than $30 USD since that is the cost of Universe Sandbox.

Comment: Celestia? That is free.

Comment: I think I tried Celestia, but the fact that it needed to be coded for anything new deterred me from getting into it. Perhaps I'll have to give that one a try again and learn how to add in the bodies.

Comment: Also I've played a little bit with Celestia source already, and well... it is not really tuned for easy extendibility, that was my experience. But you don't need to extend, it is enough if you can somehow inject your own db into it. I am not sure, if Celestia can even simulate gravitational n-body systems, too.

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35643/32009

Comment: The planetary system is in the link I previously showed (accidentally hit post before I was done). Therefore I don't think a gravity engine is as relevant. That being said, it's always a plus